# Proving surjectivity using Rank-nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: a]

At the last step, we have that $\dim (V) = n = \dim(k^n)$, so the rank nullity theorem gives that $\dim(Im(T)) + \dim(Ker(T)) = n$ but how does this give that $T$ is surjective? I understand that if we show that $\dim(Im(T)) = n$ then seeing as $T$ is injective we can conclude it is surjective, but I don't know how the rank-nullity theorem gives that $\dim(Im(T)) = n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** $Im(T)$ is a linear subspace of $k^n$ that has dimension $n$, which is equal to the dimension of $k^n$. Use that every basis for a linear subspace can be extended to a basis for the whole space.

**PS:** Remember that [the rank nullity theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rank-NullityTheorem.html) states that $\dim(Im(T)) + \dim(Ker(T))=\dim(V)$.

**PS':** Since $T$ is injective, $ker(T)=\{0\}$. Since the dimension of the zero linear subspace is $0$ (why?), you have $\dim (ker(T))=0$.

Comment: but how does that use the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: Exactly how you used it. Are you complaining about the use of the rank-nullity theorem or about why this implies the result?

Comment: ah I didn't see that $ker(T) = \{0\}$ thanks again, I see why it is too

Comment: Ah Ok. That's equivalent to "$T$ is injective".

Comment: Yeah silly me, thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Alright. You're welcome @DH.